# String to Localdate DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, android

I'm loading a string from SQLite database, then trying to convert it to a LocalDate so I can add it as an object parameter, then compare the date of objects on a list.

But the app crashes and gives DateTimeParseException.

This is the method that crashes, and it crashes at the line where I'm creating the LocalDate.

I have found and read many similar threads on this site and others too, but sadly I couldn't figure out what is the problem exactly.

```
private void fillEventsArray(){
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    while(data.moveToNext()){
        String name = data.getString(1);
        String description = data.getString(2);
        String time = data.getString(3);
        String date = data.getString(4);

        LocalDate localDate= LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"));

        LocalTime localTime=LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));

        Event event = new Event(name, description, localTime, localDate);

        events.add(event);
    }
```

I'm saving data in column 4 in the same "yyyy/mm/dd" format, like 2018/11/20.

Previously I also tryed turning the strings into LodalDate/LocalTime like this, but it had the same problems:

```
                String year=date.substring(0,4);
                String month=date.substring(5,7);
                String day=date.substring(8,10);
                LocalDate localDate=LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(year),Integer.parseInt(month),Integer.parseInt(day));
                String hour=time.substring(0,3);
                String minute=time.substring(4,5);
                LocalTime localTime=LocalTime.of(Integer.parseInt(hour),Integer.parseInt(minute));
```

Does it cause an error if the database is empty?

If any more information is required let me know and I'll provide it.

Logcat copy:

```
2018-11-12 15:48:57.836 12038-12038/com.example.dflavio.calendar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dflavio.calendar, PID: 12038
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dflavio.calendar/com.example.dflavio.calendar.MainActivity}: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{ceb966d VFED..CL. .F...' could not be parsed at index 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{ceb966d VFED..CL. .F...' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:394)
    at com.example.dflavio.calendar.MainActivity.fillEventsArray(MainActivity.java:104)
    at com.example.dflavio.calendar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

As somebody have pointed out I might have made a mistake at how I get the strings from my edittexts. Currently this is how the code looks:

```
createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
                EditText descriptionEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);
                EditText timeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeEditText);
                EditText dateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateEditText);

            String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
            String description = descriptionEditText.getText().toString();
            String time = timeEditText.getText().toString();
            String date = dateEditText.getText().toString();
            if (name.length() != 0){
                if (description.length() != 0){
                    if (time.length() != 0){
                        if (date.length() != 0){
                            AddData(name, description, time, date);
                            nameEditText.setText("");
                            descriptionEditText.setText("");
                            timeEditText.setText("");
                            dateEditText.setText("");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                toastMessage("Fill in all fields.");
            }
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What format is date and time stored as in the database? Do you have some example values?

Comment: Can you show the exact exception? It should contain some info indicatiing what is wrong.

Comment: @EamonScullion Not exactly sure what you mean. I used only strings all the way until this method. I basicly copied how they did it in a youtube video named "Save data into SQLite database [Beginner Android Studio Example]".

Comment: @Henry Updated post with logcat copy.

Comment: Can you post the code related to setting up the EditText?

Comment: @EamonScullion updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I' m guessing now but is it the case that when you saved this date value to the db from an EditText you did something like:

```
edittext.toString()
```

instead of

```
edittext.getText().toString()
```

If this is the case then make the change because instead of the text of the EditText you saved `"android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{ceb966d VFED..CL. .F...`

Comment: I have made the changes in code(also updated it in my post), but the app still crashes with the same error message.

Comment: @D_Flavio you have made the changes in your code, but the db still contains the non valid values. Uninstall the app from the emulator/device so the db is deleted or delete all the rows from the table, run the app again, repopulate the table and then try.

Comment: Does going into "View" -> "Tool Window" -> "Device File Explorer" -> deleting the database from the data folder work?

Comment: Yes it does, although uninstallation of the app is easier.

Comment: I actually don't know how uninstalling the app from the emulator works. I already done the database deleting and it worked, but just so I learn more how do I uninstall the app from the emulator?

Comment: Just like you do in a mobile phone, find it in all the apps and dragging it to the bin.

Answer (score 1):

Your DB seems to contain garbage; you try to parse a string like "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{ceb966d VFED..CL. .F..." as a date.

Comment: Updated my post with relevant information to your comment.

Comment: I have made the changes in code(also updated it in my post), but the app still crashes with the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly retrieving text from your Edit texts by calling `nameEditText.toString()`, which will try to convert the EditText object to a string, as you can see from the parse error.

You should be calling `nameEditText.getText().toString()`, which will get the input text from the object as a string.

Comment: I have made the changes in code(also updated it in my post), but the app still crashes with the same error message.

Comment: It would be useful if you could add a breakpoint to your `fillEventsArray` method and debug, to see what the value of `data` is when it is trying to parse

Comment: Another thing to try, you can ensure that your database is reset when running the app by adding `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);` to your `onCreate` method (add it as the first line before the table is created);

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your code reading the edittext:

Replace `timeEditText.toString();` with `timeEditText.getText().toString();`.

Comment: I have made the changes in code(also updated it in my post), but the app still crashes with the same error message.

Comment: doesn't the "/" or "-" cause problems when you are trying to turn something like "2018-11-12" into a long?

Comment: Parse a date via SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse("2018/11/12"); Then get the unix time (long) of the date object.